# Filter On Indexed, Formatted DATE

Tags: oracle, query

How do I write my calling query (without modifying `V_SPECIAL_SAMPLES`) to use the index on `sample.sample_date` (filtering by date first)?  I believe it's the TO_CHAR and TO_DATE conversions that prevent the use of the index.

Calling query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM V_SPECIAL_SAMPLES
WHERE TO_DATE ("DATE SAMPLED", 'mm/dd/yyyy  hh:mi am') > (SYSDATE - 1)
```

Table: sample

```
sample_id     NUMBER -- PK
test_type_id  NUMBER -- FK (test_type.test_type_id)
sample_date   DATE   -- indexed
```

View: V_SPECIAL_SAMPLES

```
SELECT sample_id,
       TO_CHAR(sample_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy  HH:MI AM') "DATE SAMPLED"
FROM sample
WHERE test_type_id = 5 /* 5: SPECIAL */
ORDER BY "DATE SAMPLED" DESC
```

Comment: Join `V_SPECIAL_SAMPLES` with the underlying table `SAMPLE` (using `sample_id`) and filter using `sample_date` instead of the function used in the view? Hard to tell/experiment without knowing the cardinality of the data etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `V_SPECIAL_SAMPLES` with an existing index on the `sample_date` column because of the `TO_CHAR` in the view.  Your options are

1) Don't use the view and go directly against the `sample` table.

2) Create a function based index on sample_date that does both the `TO_CHAR` and the `TO_DATE`

Something like

```
CREATE INDEX fbi_sample_date
    ON sample( to_date( to_char( sample_date, 
                                 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI AM' ),
                        'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI AM' ));
```

3) Modify the `v_special_samples` view to have both the `sample_date` as a `VARCHAR2` and to have the raw `DATE` value and filter on the raw `DATE` value.

Comment: Option 1 or Phil's option above would work.  Option 2 and 3 would work, but don't meet the requirements given.